# How to register custom directive in vue 3 <script setup>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I can't find this in the docs. There is only info on registering it global on the `app`

Is it possible to register a custom scoped directive with the `<script setup>`?

If I use regular script I have something like this:

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { customDirective } from './customDirective';

export default defineComponent({
  directives: { customDirective }
})
</script>
```

Now with `<script setup>`:

```
<script setup>
// how to register this
import { customDirective } from './customDirective';
</script>
```

If I leave it like that, I get the error in the console

`Failed to resolve directive`

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to resolve it with the `v` prefix.

```
<script setup>
import { customDirective as vCustomDirective } from './customDirective';
</script>
```

See the [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#using-custom-directives).

Comment: Is there a link in the docs to this? OP says he couldn't find docs.

Comment: @blockhead see the updated answer with the link.